# References Sync Issue with Overleaf and Mendeley

Tags: overleaf, mendeley

Something has happened to my MendeleyRefs.bib file in a project I am working on that has stopped it from updating/ syncing. During a spot of troubleshooting I re-downloaded a new Mendeley Refs' .bib file calling it MendeleyRefsNew.bib, deleted the original and updated my preamble to the new filename.

As I suspected, that did not work and I subsequently restored my original .bib file although not perfectly. I now have both .bib files and my preamble references the **new** version. This now works but I fear will create issues in a bit. Does anyone have any insight into why I need the old .bib file in my project even when it is not referenced in the preamble (and how I can fix the synchronisation issue with that file)?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue where Overleaf was looking for an old .bib file. I solved it by:

-clicking on the arrow next to the green compile button

-clicking "recompile from scratch" on the bottom of the list

-recompiling again